# How to update web page after successfull ajax request without reload the page

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I am sending the AJAX request to server and after success I would like to update the page without refreshing it fully. It is my snippet of code, but here I can just reloading the page and not sure how to do that without it, my line does not work either, could you help, please?

PS. I am using Django for back-end

```
function saveTags(slug, form, e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let tags = form.getElementsByClassName("new-tags")[0].value;
        if (tags != '') {
            var formData = {
              csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
              slug: slug,
              tags: tags,
            };
            var POST_URL = "{% url 'save_tags' %}";
            $.ajax({
                url: POST_URL,
                type: "POST",
                data:   formData,
                success: function (data) {
                  var x = document.getElementById("snackbar");
                  x.classList.add("show");
                  setTimeout(function(){ x.className = x.className.replace("show", ""); }, 3000);
                  $("document").html(data);
                  //window.location.reload(true);
                }
            }); // end ajax
        }
        return false;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

in your Django view you should render the template using `django.template.loader.render_to_string`, then using `django.http.HttpResponse` return it.

on your frontend you can do something like `.success(data => $("body").html(data))`

the key is that you should explicitly render your template into string